# React-Native always call SwitchNavigator in component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to create a function which checks if a user is still signed in. If it's not then, go back to sign in screen.
But, I want it to always go to the Auth without having to give every screen a navigation prop. Instead I want to have it inside of a component so that I can import it and call it whenever I need the same.
Im new to react-native and have not found anything about how I can do this.

The switch navigator is in app.js like this:

```
    const App = createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
      Starter: AuthLoadingScreen, 
      App: AppStack, 
      Auth: AuthStack
  }, 
  {
      initialRouteName: 'Starter'
  }
));
```

sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i would suggest is like i can see is your initial page is Starter as in

```
 {
      initialRouteName: 'Starter'
  }
```

So suppose you have succesfully logged in , after that i suppose you will get a token, so store it in AsyncStorage.

Now suppose next time user opens the app , what you can do is in Starter page's componentDidMount add the below code

```
async componentDidMount(){
await AsyncStorage.getItem("token")?this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeScreen"):this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen")
}
```

so basically you are checking in the inital page if token exists in asyncstorage, and if it exists navigate to homescreen otherwise redirect to login screen where user will authenticate.

Hope thats clear. feel free for doubts.

check this for asyncstorage [async storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to have it inside of a component so that I can import it and call it whenever I need the same.

For this you can create a separate function to check if user is logged in or not and export it. Then where ever you need it, you can import it and call it to see if user is still logged in. Then do operation accordingly.

```
export const checkUser = () => {
    if(loggedIn) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Then,

```
import {checkUser} from 'path to file where declared'

if(checkUser()) {
    // user logged in
} else {
    // move to login
}
```

Comment: Can you set the navigation prop in checkuser component without having to get anything give any navigation when called?

Comment: @Bluetodark didn't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: Can you add navigation in the checkUser component and that in always navigate without having to pass it a prop.

Comment: @Bluetodark If you mean to say you want to navigate without the `navigation` prop then you can follow this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html